# command to find the number of connections in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a requirement ti find the number of connections in mongodb. I used the command below to find that

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

It gave me the output as below

```
{ "current" : 3, "available" : 19997 }
```

I have say 4 individual dbs in the mongodb,how do i find the connection status for the individual dbs rather than the whole list.I am stuck here any help will be much helpful

Comment: `db.currentOp()` can show it I beieve

Comment: @Sammaye :say if i have 2 dbs of names a and b can i get the status of the individual dbs like a:{"current":1,"available":8989},b:{"current":1,"available":8989}